# Using Python to gather attributes

Tags: qgis, python

I have a shapefile that has been drawn to encompass certain points in another layer.  I can use the intersection feature to gather all the data from the points layer, for points that lie in this polygon I have drawn.  However, I need to be able to export this to CSV.

How can I write a Python script that will pull all the points data that lie within this polygon.

```
points layer = ("xyz")
polygon layer = ("abc")
```

I am looking to have all the data from the points layer that are within my polygon layer.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use [***Select Features by Polygon***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCcSV.png) (click the small arrow on the right of the selection button) and then, using [***Save Selected Features As***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSxGD.png) from the layers panel, export the selection as a CSV file.

Links are to screenshots.